# Navigation Drawer opens to different fragments

Tags: android-fragments

I am a beginner when it comes to Android. I have spent hours reading tutorials, watching videos, and combing through stackoverflow trying to figure this out. Even with all the online resources available , I still can't figure this out.

I want my list view always on the main screen, but when I swipe I want the navigation drawer to slide in and display a different fragment depending on which item in the list view has been selected. For example if the user selected 'account', when they slide from the right the account fragment would display.

I've left in 'navList' and 'nav2List' for testing, but I would like these to be fragments.

### XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bankMenu"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
<!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/nav2List"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### JAVA

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView menu;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ListView secondDrawerList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        menu =        (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bankMenu);
        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
        secondDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.nav2List);
        addBankingListItems();  // populate the banking items list

        menu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    final int position, long id) {

                // ListView Clicked item index
                int itemPosition = position;

                // ListView Clicked item value
                String itemValue = (String) menu.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Show Alert
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : " + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                if (itemPosition < 4) {  // TESTING FUNCTIONALITY
                    addDrawerItems();
                } else {
                    addSecondDrawerItems();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

---EDIT---
This issue has been resolved. 
In the xml file, i changed the two ListViews to a RelativeView.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_to_be_replaced"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topRL"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee">

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the MainActivity, I created a fragment manager, then after my switch statement, i replaced the frame with the required one. Hope this can help someone, send me a pm for more info.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
switch (itemPosition) {

                case 0:
                    fragment = MyFrag1.newInstance("", ""); // fragment declared above
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = MyFrag2.newInstance("", "");
                    break;
                case 2: etc....
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_to_be_replaced, fragment)
                    .commit();
```